# Excel Macro - Automate Filename

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, auto-increment

Solved thanks

I have macros that create export files for our data. We produce many files everyday so I am trying to fine tune a few things.

At the end of the macro, I would like to save the file as .xlsx with a file name the uses an incremental batch number and today's date.

Example File Names in Folder:

B001 ClientName Export 051121

B002 ClientName Export 091121

B003 ClientName Export 101121

Is there any way to automate the incremental number? Using +1 for the highest value.

The next file would then be saved as B004 ClientName Export <today's date>

I have managed to populate a message box which shows the current highest number my difficulty is using this to save the document with the next number

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
Const FolderPath = "Z:"
Const FileExt = "xlsx"
Debug.Print GetNextFileNum(FolderPath, FileExt)
End Sub

Public Function GetNextFileNum(ByVal TargetFolder As String, ByVal Extension As String) As Integer
Dim Folder As Object, File As Object

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = .GetFolder(TargetFolder)
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If IsNumeric(Mid(File.Name, 2, 3)) And FileExt(File.Name) = Extension Then
            GetNextFileNum = IIf(CInt(Mid(File.Name, 2, 3)) > GetNextFileNum, CInt(Mid(File.Name, 2, 3)), GetNextFileNum)
        End If
    Next File
End With

GetNextFileNum = GetNextFileNum + 1

  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "Z:" & "F00" & GetNextFileNum & " 
One " & _
    Format(Date, "ddmmyy") & ".xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Function

Public Function FileExt(ByVal Path As String) As String
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"): FileExt = .GetExtensionName(Path): End With
End Function
```

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

Toby.

You may try something like this.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
 
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
 
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
AcFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path
 
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(AcFolder)
 
Bigger = 0
 
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If Left(oFile.Name, 1) = "B" Then
       If CInt(Mid(oFile.Name, 2, 3)) > Bigger Then
          Bigger = CInt(Mid(oFile.Name, 2, 3))
       End If
    End If
Next oFile
    
    NextNumber = Bigger + 1
    MsgBox NextNumber
     
End Sub
```